# How to set pass class to function while setting class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to set a class attribute whose value is returned by calling a function which takes the class itself as parameter.

Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
def some_other_class_factory(cls):
    ...
    class SomeOtherClass:
        def __init__(self, cls):
            self.parent_cls = cls

    return SomeOtherClass(cls)

class A(object):

    some_other_class = some_other_class_factory(cls)
```

I tried to use `__new__` but that only sets the `some_other_class` attribute while a new instance is created.

Comment: and what is the benefit of such design scheme?

Comment: I think it will be useful while creating an ORM. You have a Model and a Model Manager which performs actions on that model. And for the manager to perform some operations, it needs Class on which it's going to operate. But the manage has to be accessible even when Model is not instantiated. Something like `Model.objects` from `Django`